# Creating Averages of multiple values with a join to other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables I need to create an average sum from...

Caravan Category M:1 Caravan (caravan has one category, category has many caravans)

Caravan (**Caravan_no**, rental_amount, annual_rent....

Caravan Category (**Caravan_type_id**, car_type, pets ....

Caravan Category type has such entities as; American Classic, Conventional, Twin GRP...

**I want to create an SQL query that will return a list that show the average cost for a particular caravan type**  e.g '200 'Average cost for' American Classic and so on..

NOTE: car_type has a 'check in' constraint of 8 different caravan types so this will stop the user choosing a caravan type that is not listed and messing this up.

USING ORACLE APEX 4.0

Any helpers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the below ought to do the trick (some field names may need to be changed to match your schema):

```
SELECT CC.description, AVG(C.rental_amount)
FROM CaravanCategory CC
INNER JOIN Caravan C
ON C.Caravan_Type_id = CC.Caravan_Type_id
GROUP BY CC.description
```

Comment: What is the CC and the C on inner join 'Caravan ''C'' Representing? Sorry to be abit amateur..

Comment: Hi - no worries - CC and C are just aliases that can be used to identify the source of the column references, C.rental_amount is "the rental_amount column from Caravan".

Comment: Cheers, I get what you mean but I still can not get it working, and can not figure out where I am going wrong. It is the last part of my assignment for my apex application to insert a SQL query into a region of my master detail but I have been trying for over 7 hours and can not figure where I am going wrong. Is there any companies/people who I can pay to look at my database through my online portal and write the statement for me. Then I can integrate it into my master detail application? I know it is not strictly ethical but I am really struggling.

Comment: I can't help you any further with this I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay, I just a quick question... do I need to have aliases set up, and can I just write caravan_category.description for the same result? just so I can understand it more or do I need to use aliases?

Comment: No, you don't need to use aliases - they just make the SQL more concise.